# Passing parameters in SpagoBI REST 2.0

Tags: fiware, spagobi

I wanted to use SpagoBI 2.0 REST API:
http://docs.spagobi.apiary.io/#reference

Everything seems to be fine, reports are running fine on SpagoBI server, I can get all documents via:

http://spagobi-url/SpagoBI/restful-services/2.0/documents/

I can get subreport without parameter via:
http://spagobi-url/SpagoBI/restful-services/2.0/documents/document_label/content

But I don't know how to pass parameter to run subreport with parameter?

Any clues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If someone is interested in this, this is how I done it:

You need to pass parameter in data dictionary, similar to:

values = """
  [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "label": "TABLE_ID",

      "urlName": "TABLE_ID",
      "values": [
        "3",
        "v3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "label": "TABLE_ID2",

      "urlName": "TABLE_ID2",
      "values": [
        "18",
        "v3"
      ]
    }
  ]
"""

Anyway, if someone has better explanation, please post!

Answer (score 1):

your solution is fine, but you can simplify the request body with parameters information: you just need to specify the parameters' URL name and their value, for example:

```
[
  {
    "urlName": "Position",
    "values": [
      "Store Manager"
    ]
  }
]
```

Pay attention to the fact that "subreport" means a report that is included into another bigger one, therefore your request was not so clear to me: I understood you were trying to execute just one "regular" report (that was not including other reports), is that right?

Hope this helps.

Best regards.

Davide

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I could (and probably need to) pass only urlName and it's values, I copy/pasted code from Apiary.

By term "subreport" I meant subresource, since it's Apiary's term for getting actually content od one report. Sorry if I made some mess and thank you replying!